# jQuery .attr only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I'm creating a simple quote machine with a tweet button that tweets the quote. When the page loads I simulate the "New Quote" button being pushed so the tweet button's url is updated with the quote, but after that the tweet button won't update with the new quote after the "New Quote" button is pushed.

**HTML**

```
<h1>Random Quote Generator</h1>

<p>These are some random quotes I found online by programmers. Enjoy!</p>

<button id="newQuote">New Quote</button>

<div id="quote"><span id="saying"></span><br/><i id="author"></i></div>

<a class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    t._e = [];
    t.ready = function(f) {
        t._e.push(f);
    };
    return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

quotes= ["“There are two ways of constructing a software design: One way is to make it so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies, and the other way is to make it so complicated that there are no obvious deficiencies. The first method is far more difficult.”/- C.A.R. Hoare", "“If debugging is the process of removing software bugs, then programming must be the process of putting them in.”/- Edsger Dijkstra", "“Measuring programming progress by lines of code is like measuring aircraft building progress by weight.”/- Bill Gates", "“Nine people can’t make a baby in a month.” (regarding the addition of more programmers to get a project completed faster)/– Fred Brooks", "“Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.”/– Brian W. Kernighan", "“Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live.”/– Martin Golding", "“C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot; C++ makes it harder, but when you do, it blows away your whole leg.”/– Bjarne Stroustrup", "“When debugging, novices insert corrective code; experts remove defective code.”/– Richard Pattis", "“Computer science education cannot make anybody an expert programmer any more than studying brushes and pigment can make somebody an expert painter.”/– Eric S. Raymond", "“Most good programmers do programming not because they expect to get paid or get adulation by the public, but because it is fun to program.”/– Linus Torvalds"];

$("#newQuote").on("click", function() {
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((quotes.length-1) + 1));
    quote = quotes[index].split("/");
    $("#saying").text(quote[0]);
    $("#author").text(quote[1]);
    $('.twitter-share-button').attr("href", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + quote[0] + " " + quote[1]);
});
$("#newQuote").trigger("click");

)};
```

The variable quotes being an array of strings with the quote and the author separated by a /

Comment: You may be running off the end of the array with that +1 on the end. Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: try bind click in next way : `$("body").on("click", "#newQuote", function() {`

Comment: No I didn't get an error. I should have probably mentioned you can see it here on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/RickCoxDev/pen/WQKgGM)

Comment: I use Chrome and it works.

Comment: Still doesn't for me. Tweet button href attribute stays the same for the original quote when the page loads.

Comment: Works for me in IE and Chrome.  Can you share more of the code, including the creation of the array, and the includes?

Comment: @demo: It is a single element, identified by ID selector, that exists at startup (or the first popup would not work). This is the one case where a delegated event handler is certainly not called for :) Also, never use `body` as the default as it has a bug, use `document`

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/a14t430s/

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye, yeah, you are right :D for Id there is no sense of doing it

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is that index is global scoped because of the lack of "var index ..."

also you should use .click(function(){...}); to bind onclick events to dom.

Comment: As `index` is set *and used* immediately, that is an unlikely cause. `click` is equally valid, but is certainly not a "should use" case :) `on` is more easily converted to delegated events, so is often my preference.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough at the very bottom of your javascript, these two characters are reversed.  Maybe that's it?

```
)};
```

Should be

```
});
```